# Cologne or toilet water?

Tags: word-choice, nouns, american-english, history, french

I am writing a novel set in 1890s Georgia (United States), and I am wondering whether the main character, a young man of eighteen, would refer to *eau de toilette* as *cologne*, *toilet water*, or something else entirely. Any ideas?

Comment: I think it depends greatly on the social class of the young man. And is it for his use or a girl's?

Comment: James is a young man from a wealthy Macon family. And the cologne actually belongs to his college roommate, John.

Answer (score 2):

Cologne would work it seems (but it is also the city. Perhaps cologne-water, would be better)

[eau de toilette, eau de cologne, cologne, toilet water between 1800 and 1890 from the corpus of American English](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=eau+de+toilette%2Ceau+de+cologne%2Ccologne%2Ctoilet+water&year_start=1800&year_end=1890&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=)

[image: NGram]

Comment: Cologne is the city, not cologne. Ngrams is case sensitive, so you're in no danger there.

Comment: Well, if I click on some of the links I saw the city

Comment: Interesting. I wonder if ngrams uses a different search to the books search it links to.